# In Travis for my Angular.js project I get bower install error

Tags: angularjs, bower, travis-ci

I have a basic angular project on github based off of Angular Seed. I have travis set up to do testing, and it keeps getting this error:

```
npm ERR! angular-seed@0.0.0 postinstall: `bower install`
```

This is the full output:
https://travis-ci.org/RobKohr/islandwarfare.com/builds/44103657

and this is the commit:
https://github.com/RobKohr/islandwarfare.com/commit/0a8b1c373c8a5b5736f8c236633755bff353b164

How can I stop this error from occuring?

Answer (score 1):

The postinstall step of your package is running `bower install` - this is the failing part of the build (as indicated by the error).
bower install fails since Bower is unable to find a suitable version of angular. This happens different version of angular are required by your package dependencies. In this case this is the conflict as presented by bower:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.27 which resolved to 1.2.27 and is required by angular-loader#1.2.27, angularmocks#1.2.27, angular-route#1.2.27
    2) angular#1.2.x which resolved to 1.2.27 and is required by angular-seed
    3) angular#1.3.6 which resolved to 1.3.6 and is required by angular-resource#1.3.6
```

You can solve this conflict by forcing a specific version of angular in your bower.json. For example to force the resolution of angular 1.2.27 add the following:

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.27"
  }
```